# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForClientDebug'

Tags: android

The error
[image]

My gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
    compile project(':venuemap')
    //    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    //    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    //    compile     "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
//    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    // compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    // compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.1'
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-        core:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
// annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

android {
    def defaultApplicationId = "com.yamo.android"

    def defaultVersionName = "1.1.7"

    def buildNumber = "53" // increment when merging with master
    def defaultVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(buildNumber)

    def buildNumberSuffix = " (" + buildNumber + ")"

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        applicationId defaultApplicationId
        versionCode defaultVersionCode
        versionName defaultVersionName
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       // multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile rootProject.file("keystore/debug.keystore")
        }

        release {
            storeFile rootProject.file("keystore/release.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "locassa"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        live {
            versionName defaultVersionName + buildNumberSuffix
        }

        client {
            versionName defaultVersionName + "-CLIENT" + buildNumberSuffix
            applicationId defaultApplicationId
        }

        internal {
            versionName defaultVersionName + "-INTERNAL" +     buildNumberSuffix
            applicationId defaultApplicationId + ".internal"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    //apply from: 
    rootProject.file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.gradle')
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

When building app,  I have got this error.
I am using android studio 2.3.3.
CompileSdkVersion is 26 and buildToolsVersion is 26.0.2.
And my gradle version is 2.3.3.
I have been searching the solution about this problem for several days but I didn't find anything on google.
Please help me to resolve this error.   Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you upload the full error log? The one in `Gradle Console` view.

Comment: Thanks for your replying.  I have already uploaded error screen image.
Just one error.

Comment: That's the event log, not the Gradle log. Fine, run the gradle build in terminal with --stacktrace or --debug options to get the full long.

Comment: try disable instant run in settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your Problem :

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

Use this :

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'
```